# If $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence. Then prove: $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n$

Tags: real-analysis

If $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence. Then prove:

$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n=\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ x_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n$$

My attempt:

We know by hypothesis $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n=x\tag1$$
Let $E(X_n)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: \text{exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_k\subset\{x_n\}_n$ such that $x_{n_k}\rightarrow x$ when $k\rightarrow \infty$ }\}$

Then $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n$ By definition is the supremum of $E(X_n)$.

Here I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you know that every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same thing?

Comment: Yes, i know that @RobertWolfe that implies $Sup(E(X_n))=x$ is correct?

Comment: yes, as well as $\inf E(X_n)=x$.

Comment: Thanks for all @RobertWolfe